# Fatal Error Exception class app\http\controllers\controller not found

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, classnotfoundexception

Fatal Error

> Exception class app\http\controllers\controller not found

while I run the command php artisan route:list and other all commands are working correctly.
I have named my project as "Socialite" and give namespace to controller.php as "namespace Socialite\Http\Controllers;". I also auto-dumped my project.
there is no any syntax error in routes/web.php.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('start');



Route::get('/signup','HomeController@getSignup')->name('auth.signup');
Route::post('/signup','HomeController@postSignup')->name('auth.signup');

Route::get('/signin','HomeController@getSignin')->name('auth.signin');
Route::post('/signin','HomeController@postSignin')->name('auth.signin');
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: LOL! I think you mean 'Fatal Error'!

Answer (score 0):

You should use this command to rename an app:

```
php artisan app:name Socialite
```

Or change namespace of all classes your app uses manually, for example for `Controller.php` namespace will be:

```
namespace Socialite\Http\Controllers;
```